# How to use argument as variable within variable statement in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, arguments

This may be an obvious search, but I'm not totally sure on the proper syntax... basically what I want to do is:

```
        private function makeISchedule(data:Array, label:String = null):ArrayCollection{
            var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;

            for (var i:int = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                var isched:SimpleScheduleEntry = new SimpleScheduleEntry;
                isched.startDate = dater.parseString( data[i].DateTime );
                isched.endDate = dater.parseString( data[i].EndDateTime );
                if (label != null){
                    isched.label = data[i].label;
                }
                arr.addItem( isched );
            }
            return arr;
        }
```

the problem is .label.. it looks for the actual 'label' field rather than using the label string that's been passed to the function. How can I get the 'label' to be read as the argument variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after is:

```
isched.label = data[i][label];
```

Comment: haha.. it really was right there in front of me wasn't it. thanks!